# PHP sql query does not return table content

Tags: php, sql

I want to execute a simple sqlsrv_query query in php. To do so, I installed the MS Drivers and was able to establish a connection to my DB (SQL Server Management Studio 18.9.2). What I don´t understand is the message `Resource id #3`, which I believe is neither an failure or error. I expect a raw echo / print_r of the table content. What do I miss?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM nodes";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

if ($stmt === false) {
    die (print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
} else {
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch($stmt))
    print_r($row);
    print_r($stmt);
    echo "<br />Statement executed";
}
```

The table looks like:

[image]

Error I get:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use sqlsrv_fetch_array statement instead of the sqlsrv_fetch.

```
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    // print_r($row);
    print($row["nodes"] . "<br>");
}
```

Comment: I think a better method can be using PDO instead of SQLSRV functions.

Comment: thanks for your hint which I tested. The ressource #id 3 message is gone but I also do not receive any further result. Just pure blank, after the "Connection established" message.

Comment: I modified the answer, try it please. I think the name of your column is "nodes".